# How do you count the time signatures of classical music?

Tags: time-signatures, classical-music

i'm trying to begin writing simple classical pieces but i don't want the movement to have a standard 4/4 feel.

does a piece like [gustav mahler - piano quartet in a minor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPXinFjtIyg) have a time signature?

if so, how do i find it?

Comment: I guess, that in the title *count* should be replaced by *find*. Was this your question?

Comment: You could, you know, try looking at the score :-).  It's not hard to find at least some sample pages of almost any sheet music online.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Your comment is actually an answer and  adds nothing to already existing answers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, practically any classical piece of music has one or more time signatures (due to having more than one movement, or due to changing it in the middle of one, possibly several times also). The easiest way to find it, is, to look into the [score (here: IMSLP)](http://imslp.org/wiki/Piano_Quartet_(Mahler,_Gustav)). If you don't find one online (as here), a library may have a copy.

Answer (score 2):

The question is ambiguous. To *find* it, you need to look at the sheet music or score. To *find what it is* you listen, often very carefully. Every so often, you'll hear, or feel, a note that seems to be more emphasised than the others around it.That point is also where a new section of tune, or phrase starts. Count 1 there, and if you can sense the pulse of the music, keep counting at that tempo until you hear another more emphasised note. That's usually the next 1. So, if you manage to count, say, 1,2,3 and that 1 occurs next, the piece is in 3. It's not quite as simple as that, with compound time sigs., but it's a good start. Do not necessarily take the first note as a '1', because there are anacruces which can be red herrings.

Answer (score 1):

You can deduce the time signature of a piece by listening to it if you have sufficient experience, but that method isn't foolproof because you *might* confuse e.g. 6/4 for 3/4 with a very regular phrase structure, or for a very slow 6/8.

For a particular piece, the thing to do is to read its score. As guidot wrote, this score is in fact freely available on the internet. so you can see for yourself that it is notated as 2/2.